# мілезім чи мілезим?

Tags: правопис

Мова про винарський термін, запозичений з французької мови: **millésime**
Як правильно передати його українською?
Трапляється чотири варіанти: мілезим, мілезім, міллезім, міллезим.
На жаль, спеціалізованих словників поки що, здається, не існує, звідки такий правописний безлад.

Comment: Якщо відповідь покриває ваше запитання і вас влаштовує її якість, то ви можете її прийняти натиснувши на галочку.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

За прапописом мало б бути ***мілезим***:

- Чому *-і-*, а не *-и-* після *м-*.

  > [[§ 129.I.6]](https://mon.gov.ua/storage/app/media/zagalna%20serednya/%202019.pdf#page=128) І пишемо: <…> У всіх інших випадках після б, п, в, м, ф, г, к, х, л,н перед наступним приголосним: бі́знес, піло́т, вібра́ція, акаде́мік, фіна́нси, гра́фік, гіпопота́м, логі́чний, гі́мн, кібу́ц, кілогра́м, кіно́, архі́в, хі́мія, хіру́рг, літерату́ра, респу́бліка, ні́ша, піані́симо.
  >
  > За усталеною традицією в ряді слів іншомовного походження, що давно засвоєні українською мовою, після б, п, в, м, ф, г, к, х, л, н пишемо и: башки́р, ви́мпел, єхи́дна, імби́р, калми́к, кипари́с, кисе́т, лима́н, ми́ля, мирт, ни́рка, спирт, химе́ра та ін. [Але мілезим не схоже на давно засвоєне слово, що має усталену традицію.]
  >
  > За традицією з и пишемо також слова грецького походження, що усталилися в церковному вжитку: дия́кон, єпи́скоп, єпити́мія́, єпитрахи́ль, ми́ро, ми́тра, митрополи́т, христия́нство тощо. [Але мілезим не грецького походження.]
- Чому *-л-*, а не *-лл-* чи щось інше.

  - Чому *-л-*, а не *-лл-*.

    > [[§ 128.1]](https://mon.gov.ua/storage/app/media/zagalna%20serednya/%202019.pdf#page=126) У загальних назвах іншомовного походження букви на позначення приголосних звичайно не подвоюємо: аба́т, акумулятор, баро́ко, беладо́на, белетри́стика, браві́симо, ват, гру́па, гун (гу́ни), ідилі́чний, інтелектуа́льний, інтерме́цо, колекти́в, комі́сія, лібре́то, піані́симо, піцика́то, стака́то, су́ма, фін (фі́ни), шасі́ та ін.
    >
    > За традицією з подвоєнням пишемо загальні назви: анна́ли, бо́нна, білль, бру́тто, бу́лла, ва́нна, ві́лла, до́нна, мадо́нна, ма́нна, мулла́, панно́, пе́нні, то́нна, ду́рра, мі́рра та слово Алла́х.
  - Чому *-л(л)-*, а не *-й-*.

    Є [§ 125](https://mon.gov.ua/storage/app/media/zagalna%20serednya/%202019.pdf#page=125), згідно з яким «французькі буквосполучення ll та ill після голосних, у кінці слів та перед голосними відповідно до французької вимови [!] передаємо через й: макія́ж, Війо́н, Шантії́». Однак у цьому разі французька вимова має -л(л)-, а не -й-, порівняйте:
    [maquillage](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/maquillage#Pronunciation_3) (макіяж) → /ma.ki.jaʒ/ (через /j/),
    [millésime](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mill%C3%A9sime#Pronunciation) → /mi.le.zim/ (через /l/).
- Чому *-и-*, а не *-і-* після *з-*.

  > [[§ 129.III.1]](https://mon.gov.ua/storage/app/media/zagalna%20serednya/%202019.pdf#page=128) И пишемо: <…> У загальних назвах після приголосних д, т, з (дз), с, ц, ж (дж), ч, ш, р перед наступним приголосним (крім й): ди́зель, дина́мо, дипло́м, дире́ктор, мето́дика; інститу́т, матема́тика, сти́мул, тип; пози́ція, фізи́чний; такси́ст, родзи́нка, силуе́т, систе́ма; цисте́рна, ци́фра; режи́м, джигі́т, джинси, джип; чичеро́не; ши́рма, шифр; брига́да, риф, фа́брика.

Вікіпедія наразі також пише *[мілезим](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D1%96%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%BC)* (але без джерел).

Але оскільки слово не усталилося, то остаточно вирішити, мені здається, поки не можна.